# Ember Data's find method: handling SQL 'OR' equivalent query

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

i'm new to ember, and have implement Ember Data for data retrieval within my app.

I wish to retrieve a list of articles that are either in the 'Beauty' or 'Health' category.

The SQL equivalent is:

`from article where category = "Beauty" OR category = "Health"`

How should I do this using Ember Data?

**I've tried:**

`this.store.find('article', {category: ['Beauty', 'Health']}`

but this results in a poorly formatted GET request like:

`/articles?category%5B%5D=Beauty&category%5B%5D=Health`

Ideally i'd like the format to be: `/articles?category=Beauty&category=Health`

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%5B%5D` is the encoded version of `[]` and is perfectly valid in a URL.

Ember delegates the formatting of the request data to `jQuery.ajax`, which adds `[]` to properties containing an array. The ajax setting `traditional` tells jQuery to not add the brackets. One way to configure that in Ember is to extend the adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajaxOptions: function (url, type, hash) {
        hash = this._super(url, type, hash);
        hash.traditional = true;
        return hash;
    },
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Does setting `hash.traditional = true` cause other side effects? I'd hate for this setting to cause issues later on.